# How to make two web app talk to each other one developed with PHP and the other with python

Tags: php, python-3.x

Do I need a domain for both of the apps or I can just embed them on one server and make them communicate to each other

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "communicate" is too vague to give a proper answer. Are we talking about command-line processes or web sites? Will they run on the same server? What information do they need to exchange? Should the communication be fully interactive?

Comment: Yea they will run on thesame server each will definitely interact with database and exchange data between each other...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your complete use case, but Thats generally done using REST APIs.
You not necessarily need two domains just two directories should be suffice, so you have different urls for both code bases or you can also run them on different ports like php running on port 80 and python on 8080. the idea is having two different urls.

This link can help to understand further.

[REST APIs](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/)

Comment: U know I wonder alot how this big tech company are using lots of languages does dat means dey also gat lots of domains (u need a domain before getting a url) and use Rest API to interact with the languages because am trying to achieve Stuff in python I can't achieve in php by making communication between both

Comment: Well if you talk big companies they do work mostly on micro-service architecture. where all services communicate each other using some mechanism such as REST. in general you just have to make sure endpoints are different using urls or ports or any other DNS mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to help!

Well, using domain is a way to solve the problem, but i think translate data on server will be more safe and quick.

**Notice: PHP and Python app must be on the same server**

I'll give the example code below.

In my code, suppose that PHP dir is `/var/www/`, and Python dir is `/var/py/`. You can change them yourself.

Python(/var/py/a.py):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding:utf-8
import sys
import subprocess

# python get message from php.
a=sys.argv[0]
b=a.split("&&");
# You can do what you want to b[] ~

# python send message to php 
subprocess.call("php -f /var/www/b.php a=username&&b=pass&&c=haha")
```

PHP(/var/www/b.php):

```php
//php send message to python
system("python /var/py/a.py a=username&&b=pass&&c=haha");

//php get message from python
$dat=explode($argv[1],"&&");
//you can do what you want to $dat ~
```

P.S.: my code doesn't have **return value**. If you want to get return value after `system()` or `subprocess.call()`, please comment and i'll write them.

Wish you a good day:)

Comment: Ok thanks for this, I never hosted any website on server already u mean I can host both the apps on thesame server and translate them on the server I think that will be great thanks is dat also similar with API calls

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is a cloud hosting, then php can run on port 80 while python on 81 or any other port.
So 127.0.0.1 for php and 127.0.0.1:81 for python

Comment: Ok cloud hosting gives dat possibility what if am not using a cloud hosting do I need more domains because it will be horrible to keep lots of domains

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need cloud hosting to make this possible